# How to retrieve and save a added custom field in code

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom field (UsrMyCustomField) on the customers screen under Accounts Recievable.  I have verified it has been created on the baccount table and I can save it through the website no worries.

How through code can I access this custom field?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which technique you use to create your custom field. There are 2 ways to access your custom field

ACE:

```
BAccount.UsrMyCustomField/Customer.UsrMyCustomField
```

(in case your custom field created under Customer class)

AEF, let's assume your field created under extension class, for example: BAccountExt

```
BAccountExt ext = PXCache<BAccount>.GetExtension<BAccountExt>(yourBAccountRow)();
ext.UsrMyCustomField;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.  Your reply helped  I added the custom field through a customisation project though the website.

I had to generate the BAccount class onto my visual studio solution for it to work with BAccount.

Comment: My problem now is when I come to save the custom field in code.

I am using the CustomerMaint graph and PX.Object.AR.Customer class to enter details and persist the changes.  How do I set the custom field value through here?

When I look at graph.BAccount.Current it returns the customer class where my custom field is not visible.

Comment: I think you should retrieve BAccount record based on your current Customer record. Btw, Customer.CustomerID is based on BAccount.BAccountID. You can select BAccount table by using CustomerID